Formula for converting monthly percentages from a 12 month distribution into x number of months
(Please let me know if this needs any clarification)
I have a client that builds homes and we want to model billings across any project duraction, according to the average monthly percentages from a 12 month distribution.
Example:
Project A will take 12 months. We can expect monthly billings of the total construciton cost to be:
Mo. 1 : 1%
Mo. 2 : 5%
Mo. 3 : 7%
Mo. 4 : 14%
Mo. 5 : 15%
Mo. 6 : 22%
Mo. 7 : 11%
Mo. 8 : 7%
Mo. 9 : 6%
Mo. 10 : 6%
Mo. 11 : 5%
Mo. 12 : 1%
However, the next project could be anywhere from 2 to 18 months.
What formula (and mathematical concept, domain) may I use to convert the 12 month distribution percentages into monthly percentages when the duration is not a perfect 12 months?

What you're talking about could be a simple matter of scaling/normalizing. Turn the duration (in your case month) into a percent of the way through the project, and you can calculate and communicate in terms of how far along a project is. This assumes that project completion/billing distribution is generally similar regardless of duration, which I suspect is not the case, but might not matter for this kind of straightforward modeling. It will show up most when the duration is most disparate.
For example, a 2 month project might look like this

Mo. 1 : 40%
Mo. 2 : 60%

which becomes

Scaled Duration 0.5 : 40%
Scaled Duration 1.0 : 60%

A 5 month project might look like this

Mo. 1 : 6%
Mo. 2 : 21%
Mo. 3 : 37%
Mo. 4 : 19%
Mo. 5 : 17%

which becomes

Scaled Duration 0.2: 6%
Scaled Duration 0.4: 21%
Scaled Duration 0.6: 37%
Scaled Duration 0.8: 19%
Scaled Duration 1.0: 17%

As you can see, the duration points don't always match up, but from then you can do some regressions or further modeling. You may want to do cumulative budget for regression, since every project is ending at 100% (you already scaled here!). Let me know if I can clarify anything.
